# Update data from the same table for 235 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help updating rows to equal to another set of rows for the same table for example:

```
 M005E globalpickesequense = 6627,
 globalallocationsequense = 7080,
 globalputawaysequence = 4268
```

so these numbers need to equal the same numbers as the `M005D 7607,8068,5256`.

`M006E` same thing needs to equal `M007D` globals.
and so forth...

I have to do this update for a total of 235 rows but in the image I am just adding part of rows in the database.

So if this possible to do? a query that can update all at the same time without updating row by row individually

I have been using this query where it works but I have do one by one changing the ids so that would take me too much time for all my 235 row I need a query that can do the update all at the same time

```
UPDATE  lc1
SET     lc1.globalPickSequence = lc2.globalPickSequence,
        lc1.globalAllocationSequence = lc2.globalAllocationSequence,
        lc1.globalPutAwaySequence = lc2.globalPutAwaySequence
from    mytable lc1
JOIN    mytable lc2 ON lc1.id = 27234 AND lc2.id = 16358
```

[image]

Comment: You need to have a matching expression to update many rows at once. Based on your description it seems you do not have any common expression. So you end up updating table many times. What is the relation between `M006E` and `M007D`? What is the relation between the id's `27234` and `16358`?

Comment: The 27234 and 16358 are the primary key IDs. The M006E and M007D represent a location. There is a parentid that by adding the parentid to = 10081 will bring all the 235 rows that is the only common expression they have.

Comment: Can you please post the table structure and some test data in text format?

Comment: The table structure is too huge and too many columns, so is this possible my question or not?

Comment: Without any relation between the rows, how is it possible for us to suggest a solution? The logic between `M005E` and `M005D` is only known to you. Is it always to update `????D` with values from `????E`?

Comment: I was able to resolved this issue but thanks for all the help

Comment: how did you solve this? You post your solution as an answer here.